# Communicate between application and Raspberry Ri 3 via p2p/Wi-Fi-direct

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an application where I have to communicate with an Raspberry Pi 3. Sadly, it has to be with Wi-Fi. 
My idea is the peer to peer concept, but that's not a thing I have worked on before.
I've researched about one week and the only useful site was on the developer site.
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#permissions

But this examples are not so useful to me.
I hope one of you has an idea or an example what is easier to understand.

Thanks

Comment: `Sadly, it has to be with Wi-Fi.`. "Lucky man" i would say instead. What would you have liked to use then?

Comment: I've wished a communicatin via Bluetooth. I find this solution easier, but Wifi is interesting, sure. But I´ve never been so far in android programming